# Не получается запустить Django проект на сервере (виртуальной машине) из docker-контейнера

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

Делаю проект из Яндекс-практикума. Задание такое, завернуть готовый проект на джанго в докер контейнер, закинуть на докер хаб и с помощью файла workflow на гит хабе запушить проект, он из докер хаба закидывает его на виртуальную машину, тесты у меня проходят, локально проект запускается, но сервер отдает Bad Request (400), при переходе на админскую страницу. Где искать ошибки и как отремонтировать?